# adb shell pm hide 実行エラー

Tags: android, adb

Windows 10 の PC で android 5.1.1 のタブレット端末に対して `adb shell pm hide` とコマンドを実行すると

```
Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.MANAGE_USERS.
```

というエラーメッセージが表示されます。

設定が間違っているのでしょうか？
ご教示いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: android4.xでの(block)コマンド相当が(hide)との認識で実行したいのですが

Answer (score 1):

結論から申しますとrootをとらない限り実行できません。

```
Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.MANAGE_USERS.
```

のログで示している通りMANAGE_USERSのPermissionを要求されていますが。

下記の通り、MANAGE_USERSはプリインストールされているアプリ以外には付与できません。

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#1708

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|privileged" />
```

またShellに対しても下記セキュリティ対応にてMANAGE_USERSの権限が外されています。
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f5cea03eb036c05cacc711ff90c97a48ffb2bc17%5E%21/

セキュリティパッチとしての投入なので(メーカー側が対応していれば)OS Version問わず上記パッチがあたっているはずです。

Answer (score 0):

PackageManager の hide コマンドのフォーマットは以下であるので、質問文のコマンドは正確には実行されたコマンドにパッケージ名またはコンポーネント名を指定されているかと思います。

```
pm hide [--user USER_ID] PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
```

---

> Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current
>   process has android.permission.MANAGE_USERS.

このエラーはUIDが2000のユーザ(uid=2000(shell))、またはコマンドを実行しているプロセス、つまりshellプロセスには`android.permission.MANAGE_USERS`のパーミッションが与えられていないため、セキュリティエラーとなり、コマンドが実行できないということを表しています。

以下のコマンドを実行してshellに該当のパーミッションが与えられているかを確認してください。
パーミッションがなければ該当コマンドの実行はできません。

```
adb shell dumpsys package com.android.shell
```

---

補足

手元にある以下の端末では`pm hide`コマンドは実行可能でした。

- Nexus 5 (Android 5.1.1)
- Xperia Performance (Android 6.0.1)

H.Hさんの回答にある通り、Android 6.0.1以前の端末では、メーカーの実装依存になると思います。
[Androidのセキュリティパッチのアナウンス](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2016-08-01#elevation-of-privilege-vulnerability-in-shell)
[CVEのインフォメーション](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-3833)